# label name can not be resolved

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, windowbuilder

I've created a label `loginLabel` to show message on wrong authentication. I've kept this logic inside `actionPerformed` method, but I am getting error as `loginLabel can not be resolved`. How to remove this error? I've created my GUI using window-builder.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.sql.*;

public class FirstView {

    private JFrame frmFirstProject;
    private JTextField txtUsername;
    private JPasswordField txtPassword;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FirstView window = new FirstView();
                    window.frmFirstProject.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public FirstView() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmFirstProject = new JFrame();
        frmFirstProject.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(51, 204, 204));
        frmFirstProject.setTitle("first project");
        frmFirstProject.setBounds(100, 100, 714, 491);
        frmFirstProject.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmFirstProject.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 3));
        panel.setBounds(63, 47, 580, 354);
        frmFirstProject.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username:");
        lblUsername.setBounds(24, 25, 69, 22);
        panel.add(lblUsername);

        JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password:");
        lblPassword.setBounds(24, 66, 69, 22);
        panel.add(lblPassword);

        txtUsername = new JTextField();
        txtUsername.setBounds(97, 26, 86, 20);
        panel.add(txtUsername);
        txtUsername.setColumns(10);

        txtPassword = new JPasswordField();
        txtPassword.setBounds(97, 67, 86, 20);
        panel.add(txtPassword);

        JButton btnsubmit = new JButton("submit");
        frmFirstProject.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(btnsubmit); //enter key
        btnsubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    int val = 0;
                    Connection sqlCon = DB_con.getSQLConnection();
                    PreparedStatement ps = sqlCon.prepareStatement("select 1 from tbl_user_info where username = ? and password = ?");
                    ps.setString(1, txtUsername.getText().toUpperCase());
                    ps.setString(2, String.valueOf(txtPassword.getPassword()).toUpperCase());
                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        val = rs.getInt(1);
                    }
                    if(val != 1)
                    {
                        loginLabel.setVisible(true);
                    }
                    System.out.println("the value is: "+val);
                    sqlCon.close();
                    System.exit(0);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                }

            }
        });
        btnsubmit.setBounds(94, 125, 89, 23);
        panel.add(btnsubmit);

        JPanel panel_display = new JPanel();
        panel_display.setBounds(36, 181, 355, 50);
        panel.add(panel_display);
        panel_display.setLayout(null);

        JLabel loginLabel = new JLabel("Login Authentication Mismatched. Please try again.");
        loginLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        loginLabel.setBounds(10, 11, 319, 28);
        panel_display.add(loginLabel);
        loginLabel.setVisible(false);

        JLabel lbl_header = new JLabel("LIBRARY MANAGEMENT SYSTEM");
        lbl_header.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        lbl_header.setBounds(211, 11, 288, 25);
        frmFirstProject.getContentPane().add(lbl_header);
    }
}
```

Comment: You either need to make `loginLabel` an instance field or declare it before the `ActionListener`

Comment: Any update for this question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to the local variable `loginLabel` within the anonymous ActionListener class which you previously added to `btnSubmit`. This will not work as code inside the ActionListener class (or any other class) cannot see variables that are local to a method.

Instead you should declare `loginLabel` as a field, up at the top of the class:

```
private JPasswordField txtPassword;
private JLabel loginLabel;
```

This is visible to all methods inside the class and also any non-static classes defined inside your class (such as the aforementioned `ActionListener`).

Then simply change the line which creates your label inside your initialize() method from:

```
JLabel loginLabel = new JLabel("Login Authentication Mismatched. Please try again.");
```

to

```
loginLabel = new JLabel("Login Authentication Mismatched. Please try again.");
```

Defining the loginLabel before the ActionListener will be adequate in java 8, as java 8 implicitly marks local fields that are defined but never changed as final. If you are targetting java 7 or earlier you would need to explicitly make that variable final.

Comment: Why have your reply  negative marked, I can not understand? It is better if participators leave comment for negative marking too.

Comment: I have no idea. :(

Answer (score 0):

To avoid problems like "LabelX can not be resolved" or "ButtonY can not be resolved", I learned to do this:

1. On Eclipse, go to "Window" module...
2. Choose item "Preferences"...
3. Choose "WindowBuilder"...
4. Choose "Swing" or "SWT"...
5. In "Code Generation", choose "Field" in variable generation...
6. Inside "Event handlers", choose "Implement listener interface in parent class"...

[image: Preferences Eclipse IDE]

It works using Java 1.7 or 1.8. Say bye bye to errors in ActionListner Class and GUI components Swing or SWT. And sure, i'm using WindowBuilder plugin to build the GUI application.